# Remove List Items and displace the others

Tags: java, android, list, button

I have a List of Buttons and I want to delete the first and the second item. Can i move the rest of Buttons in the List so that the third Button is now the first, the 4th the second and so on?

```
for(int i = 0; i<nleer; i++){
            LinearLayout temp = layoutList.get(letzte);
            int tempid = nextButtons.get(i).getId();
            CharSequence temptext = nextButtons.get(i).getText();
            leerButtons.add(new Button(this));
            leerButtons.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
            leerButtons.get(i).setEnabled(true);
            leerButtons.get(i).setId(tempid);
            leerButtons.get(i).setText(temptext);
            leerButtons.get(i).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(myButtons.get(i).getWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tempor.addView(leerButtons.get(i));
            nextButtons.remove(i);
```

at the end i remove the Items (often i = 2) and after this loop i want to use the 3rd Item of the List but i don't know how to move them.

Comment: what happens if you try?

Comment: did u use notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: How do you make it a "list" (as ListView, in a LinearLayout or other)?

Comment: if u put some code u'll get better help.

Comment: Added a piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a List x, and you do x.remove(0) to remove the first item, the index of the first item remains 0 (all items shift forward one position). It sounds like you're asking for the default list class behavior.

Comment: I dont really  understand why my App crashes then. int l = 0; then i do the loop above  where i remove maybe 2 items of the NextButtons List; then after this loop i want to nextButtons.get(l). there should be the before 3rd item but my App crashes. If i remove the "remove" statement it works, but it shows the 2 Buttons i didn't removed too.

Comment: If you have 4 items to start, and you remove i as you increment, once you've removed two items, i = 2, number of items = 2 (indexes 0 and 1), so it fails. If you're removing items, use this: while (list.size() > 0) { ...use list.get(0);  list.remove(0); }